# Filtering by specific timeframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column with the full date and time ie 2019-01-01 00:00:00. How do I filter between specific time frames regardless of date.

For example only displaying data that falls between 07:30:00 and 19:30:00?

Thank you for the assistance. I'm completely new to R and I'm struggling with this one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ If you have tried coding a solution that didn't work it would still be useful to add the code to your post. Check out how to produce a Minimal Reproducible Example here >>> stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully reproducible example.

```
# install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
basedate = as.numeric(as.POSIXct('2019-11-11 11:11:11')) # choose a date
set.seed(1)  # make it the same every time when selecting random dates
dates =      # this generates 200 random dates from the base date
    data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F, date = as.POSIXct(basedate + 60*60*96*runif(200), origin = '1970-01-01')) %>% 
    arrange(date) %>%
    mutate(timeonly = format(date, format = '%H:%M:%S')) %>%
    mutate(keep = timeonly > '07:30' & timeonly < '19:30') %>%
    filter(keep)

#head(dates)
#        date timeonly keep
#1 2019-11-11 12:26:30 12:26:30 TRUE
#2 2019-11-11 12:28:18 12:28:18 TRUE
#3 2019-11-11 13:25:34 13:25:34 TRUE
#4 2019-11-11 14:35:53 14:35:53 TRUE
#5 2019-11-11 16:50:38 16:50:38 TRUE
#6 2019-11-11 17:07:04 17:07:04 TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to split the time into a new variable and use `hms` for the inequality.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)

df <- tibble(d = c('2010-12-13 15:30:30','2018-05-13 01:20:30', '2015-03-22 08:55:18'))

df %>%
  separate(d, into = c('date','time'), sep = ' ') %>%
  mutate(
    time = as_hms(time)
  ) %>%
  filter(time > parse_hms('07:30:30') & time < parse_hms('19:30:30'))
```